# C# LINQ EntityFramework trouble

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a property that executes a LINQ query. Why does it return a bool? How can I make it return an instance of my ORMClass?

```
public string ContactPersonName
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToString(
            Client.ContactPersons.Select(x => x.MainContactPerson == true).First()
        );
    }
}
```

I want some of

```
((ContactPerson)Client.ContactPersons.Select(x => x.MainContactPerson == true).First())).Name //typecast error
```

Comment: Where is the property reference for the name of `MainContactPerson`?  Can you show us the `ContacPerson` class?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Where` to filter instead of `Select`

```
Client.ContactPersons.Where(x => x.MainContactPerson).First();
```

For simpler:

```
Client.ContactPersons.First(x => x.MainContactPerson);
```

Comment: For my own clarification, do you suggest using `Where` or `First`?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `Select` when you really want a `Where`

```
public string ContactPersonName
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToString(
            (
                Client.ContactPersons.Where(x => x.MainContactPerson == true).First())
            )
            ;
    }
}
```